# Fitting when variables have different variances?

Tags: python, r, matlab, least-squares

I am trying to fit a function y = f(x1,x2,x3). The function is non-linear and variables x1,x2, and x3 have different variances. In such a case how do I weigh different variables while performing a least-squares fit? Any examples would help.

For example, below is the covariance matrix of the data obtained at one location:

```
 0.0039   -0.0001   -0.0054
-0.0001    0.0037    0.0003
-0.0054    0.0003    0.8037
```

At another location, the covariance matrix is below:

```
0.0460    0.0000    0.0030
0.0000    0.0408    0.0003
0.0030    0.0003    0.2943
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any adjustment.

Comment: If you are using nls then it is done conditional on the values of the independent variables so their distribution does not enter.  The weights in nls are for cases, not the variables.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to a reference for this? Also, I didn't understand your last sentence - what do you mean by "cases"?